# Floating desk on concrete block wall

Tags: mounting, desk, concrete-block

I have a concrete block wall with dot and dab plasterboard. I am looking to attach a wall to wall floating desk to it. I appreciate a number of questions relating to floating desks have been asked previously and I have read through these but still have some questions.

A picture of the intended design below:

[image: A plan showing the layout and dimensions intended desk]

The desk will be utilised for two sets of keyboards and mice only. The monitors are wall mounted and the rest is located elsewhere. That said, I think it is important that it can take the weight of an individual sitting on the edge of it - as people do!

I appear to have three choices of how to mount the floating desk.

1) The first is to run wooden battens around the three sides of the desk and effectively rest it in place. This appears to be the weakest option as with the desk being over 2m wide, it is likely to sag. Also, it seems unlikely to sufficiently take the weight of someone resting themselves on it.

2) To use L shaped brackets such as these. I am assuming these can be attached directly to the concrete block walls using expanding sleeve anchors but I have concerns as to whether they will simply pull out. I am also unclear on whether there is a solution that would enable me to attach these directly over the plasterboard (as there is a gap between the plasterboard and the concrete block, so I imagine some kind of spacer would be needed) or whether I'd need to remove the plasterboard then apply directly to the concrete block.

[image: L bracket]

3) To use a bracket that is side mounted onto wooden studs. To achieve this, I would need to build a half height stud wall and attach this to the concrete block work. These brackets would then be attached to the stud work, then new plasterboard applied to the studs. If this is the preferred route, how would I effectively ensure the stud work was attached sufficiently securely to the concrete block work so it did not simply pull away?

[image: Floating desk bracket]

Any suggestions or input on my options appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Because it's surrounded by walls, it's not really floating. Given that, you don't have to build it with floating limitations, even if it's a cool idea. I would do something like option #1, but with vertical boards from the floor holding up the rail (batten); basically lining the lower part of the walls with boards, like sideways studs. This would provide enormous strength and a simple build, at the cost of slightly thicker walls under the desk. You can toggle bolt the box into the wall so it can't tip, but most of the forces would be on the "studs". Maybe add brackets from #2 to the back...

Comment: @dandavis Sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your reply. Not sure I have fully understood so just want to check. Are you effectively saying build a stud wall up in front of the concrete block and rest the desk on top of it (as if it were just a wall mounted batten). Then all the weight would push down onto the floor rather than off the wall?

Comment: @ChrisEvans: basically, but with studs flat against the wall or just 2x2s. It occoured to me later you could line the wall under the desk with plywood, and optionally attach battons to that, somewhat like i described above but with even less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardest piece of your question is the sag and being able to support the weight of someone resting at the mid point.

A 2x4 ledger attached to the 3 walls to support the desk solves everything except the sag.

At ~7ft across, for the sag the best option is probably metal angle iron set back 6" from the front and secured to the side walls using either a bracket or the ledge used to the support the desk.  Maybe a 2"x2" angle iron at 3/8 thickness.  You could also use a couple brackets from #2 to add support to the angle iron from the back wall.

Answer (score 1):

The sagging potential is not necessarily related to the "wooden battens" in option 1. It is dependent on the material the desk top is made of.

A top made of thick enough strong material will not sag ( unless a sufficient weight is placed on it for an extended amount of time). 
 You could add a piece of angle iron or something underneath to beef up the top.

**Or use the brackets i referenced in this question**. [Floating desk](http://The%20sagging%20potential%20is%20not%20necessarily%20related%20to%20the%20%22wooden%20battens%22%20in%20option%201.%20It%20is%20dependent%20on%20the%20material%20the%20desk%20top%20is%20made%20of.%20You%20could%20add%20a%20piece%20of%20angle%20iron%20or%20something%20underneath%20to%20beef%20up%20the%20top.%20Or%20use%20the%20brackets%20i%20referenced%20in%20this%20question.%20diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114905/%E2%80%A6%20-%20With%20the%20proper%20anchors%20for%20concrete%20it%20will%20be%20solid.)

- *With the proper anchors for concrete it will be solid.*